# Get last characters in a filename using a batch file

Tags: batch, batch-file, logging, filenames

i want to have a batch file that run on start up and log when the computer started and for how long it was on. this is the code i use to log when i start the computer:

```
echo Date:%date% Time:%time% >> C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\log.txt
```

Here is my idea for a code that will log "time on" as well:

```
echo Date:%date% Time:%time% >> C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\log.txt

set /a variableA=0

:a

timeout 60 /nobreak

set /a variableA=%variableA%

set /a variableB=%variableA%+1

del "C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\templogfile_%variableA%.txt"

echo.>"C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\templogfile_%variableB%.txt"

goto a
```

This batch file will start on start up and log for how long the computer was on last time and then add the date and time for this time. then it will start to count the minutes for this time and add them as well next time the computer starts. I only need help with the following part:

What should I put after `templogfile_` in

```
`"C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\templogfile_*" >> C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\log.txt
```

Comment: someone just editet my post and changed the question.
i dont need to know what i shoud put after templogfile_

Comment: Please dont edit my post if it change the issue. the edited 
version ask for something else than the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently written, your batch file always results to

```
echo.>"C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\templogfile_1.txt"
```

as `%variableB%` continues to be `1`.

However, next commented code snippet could help with extracting desired value (quoted from your original question):

> **What comes after "`templogfile_`" in**
>   "`C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\templogfile_*`"

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('
    dir /b /O:D "C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\templogfile_*"
                         ') do (
    set "_rawNumber=%%~nG"                 gets last file name e.g. templogfile_357
)
    rem there is identical output from next two ECHO commands:
    rem any text remaining in %_rawNumber% variable if `templogfile_` substring is removed
ECHO(%_rawNumber:templogfile_=%
    rem any text following 12th character in %_rawNumber% variable
ECHO(%_rawNumber:~12%
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G`, `%~nG` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`%_rawNumber:~12%`) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`%_rawNumber:templogfile_=%`) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks :)
Here are my final code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('
    dir /b /O:D "C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\templogfile_*"
                         ') do (
    set "_rawNumber=%%~nG"               
)  
set variable=%_rawNumber:~12% Minutter
echo %variable% >> C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\log.txt
echo. >> C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\log.txt
echo Date:%date%   Time:%time% >> C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\log.txt

set /a variable=0
:a
timeout 60 /nobreak
del "C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\templogfile_*.txt"
set /a variable=%variable%+1
echo.>"C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\templogfile_%variable%.txt" 
goto a
```

And here is the VBScript that makes the batchfile run in the background:

```
Dim WinScriptHost
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\Kristian\HEI\log.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Here is an example from the log:

> Date:13.09.2016   Time:21.27.00,57
>   13 Minutter
>
> Date:13.09.2016   Time:21.40.36,60
>   6 Minutter
>
> Date:13.09.2016   Time:21.49.47,20